# How to get pdfjs viewer in presentation mode on IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf.js

I am using Pdfjs for viewing pdf content, and its working well. However presentation mode works on chrome but not on Internet Explorer. Is there anything which can solve this issue?

At the moment I am opening it in new tab with the pdf path by some custom code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an internet explorer issue [Why is fullscreen mode disabled for IE11](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/9585) reported on GitHub, Please go through it, I also could not find a work around. Your approach is fine as long as user experience is the same.

Comment: You are welcome, you should always  check open issues on github if you are referring any library from there.